# Bash exited with code 1 in Azure Permission Denied

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, firebase-tools

I am facing above issue

```
2023-10-12T12:28:47.0434290Z ⚠  Authenticating with `--token` is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version of `firebase-tools`. Instead, use a service account key with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started 
2023-10-12T12:28:47.0435040Z i  uploading binary... 
2023-10-12T12:28:47.0448520Z [2023-10-12T12:28:47.044Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: []
2023-10-12T12:28:47.0461940Z [2023-10-12T12:28:47.045Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token [none]
2023-10-12T12:28:47.0463580Z [2023-10-12T12:28:47.046Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token [omitted]
2023-10-12T12:28:47.1389880Z [2023-10-12T12:28:47.138Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebase-public.firebaseio.com/cli.json 200
2023-10-12T12:28:47.1400980Z [2023-10-12T12:28:47.139Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebase-public.firebaseio.com/cli.json {"cloudBuildErrorAfter":1594252800000,"cloudBuildWarnAfter":1590019200000,"defaultNode10After":1594252800000,"minVersion":"3.0.5","node8DeploysDisabledAfter":1613390400000,"node8RuntimeDisabledAfter":1615809600000,"node8WarnAfter":1600128000000}
2023-10-12T12:28:47.1674420Z [2023-10-12T12:28:47.166Z] <<< [apiv2][status] POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token 200
2023-10-12T12:28:47.1715540Z [2023-10-12T12:28:47.167Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token [omitted]
2023-10-12T12:28:47.1719750Z [2023-10-12T12:28:47.168Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/upload/v1/projects/10118171931/apps/1:10118171931:android:5cf1871c8247e8fb5257be/releases:upload [none]
2023-10-12T12:28:47.1723630Z [2023-10-12T12:28:47.168Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/upload/v1/projects/10118171931/apps/1:10118171931:android:5cf1871c8247e8fb5257be/releases:upload [stream]
2023-10-12T12:28:47.9373760Z [2023-10-12T12:28:47.936Z] <<< [apiv2][status] POST https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/upload/v1/projects/10118171931/apps/1:10118171931:android:5cf1871c8247e8fb5257be/releases:upload 403
2023-10-12T12:28:47.9419360Z [2023-10-12T12:28:47.937Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/upload/v1/projects/10118171931/apps/1:10118171931:android:5cf1871c8247e8fb5257be/releases:upload {"error":{"code":403,"message":"The caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
2023-10-12T12:28:47.9420400Z 
2023-10-12T12:28:47.9420990Z Error: failed to upload release. HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission
2023-10-12T12:28:48.2217400Z ##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool '/bin/bash'
2023-10-12T12:28:48.2293530Z ##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/bin/bash'
2023-10-12T12:28:48.2369670Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
2023-10-12T12:28:48.2378930Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Bash exited with code '1'.
2023-10-12T12:28:48.2379490Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2023-10-12T12:28:48.2380940Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;done=true;]
```

**Deploy to firebase**

```
firebase appdistribution:distribute $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_AndroidInternalQA-CI/drop/app/build/outputs/apk/internalQA/app-internalQA.apk \
    --app 1:10142171931:android:5cf1871c9147e8fb5257be  \
    --release-notes-file  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_AndroidInternalQA-CI/drop/release_notes.txt \
    --token "Tried_updating_mY-Token_as_well"\
    --groups android---qa-internal\
   --debug
```

**Error :**

```
{
  "error":
    {
      "code":403,
      "message":"The caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"
   }
}
```

i have created new token from Firebase CI but still error not gone.

Comment: This issue looks more like a Firebase permission issue than an Azure Permission issue. Can you try not using Azure DevOps to see if you still have the same problem？